# How to hijack traffic to a port using iptables

Tags: iptables

I have an application listening on port 2000. I want to proxy all traffic to this port (originating locally) to a different port, say 4000.

Right now i am doing something like this.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2000 -d 127.0.0.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:4000
```

This works as long as there is nothing listening on 2000. if I telnet to 2000, traffic is routed to 4000 as expected. But if there is something listening on 2000, the traffic is not hijacked/proxied. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I tested this, and it made no difference if something is already listening on port 2000. Please provide more details on how to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for testing this. So here's what I did. Set up this rule. Start two listeners with `nc -l 2000` and `nc -l 4000`. Then from a different terminal connect to `nc localhost 2000`. The listener on port 2000 picks up this connection. Exit and close the listener on 2000. Now connect again, this time port 4000 gets the connection.

Comment: That is almost exactly what I did, except for the last command I typed `telnet 127.0.0.1 2000`. Can you reproduce it when typing `127.0.0.1` and not `localhost`?

Comment: Your hunch was correct! everything works as expected if I specify 127.0.0.1. Any idea what I can use as a catchall here? Thanks! I was breaking my head over it!

Comment: Does `ip6tables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2000 -d ::1 -j DNAT --to-destination '[::1]:4000'` help?

Comment: Yes, it does. This was indeed related to ipv6. I just noticed that when I started netcat in verbose mode. Thanks a lot kasperd! Please feel free to write an official answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Nice. I wrote an answer explaining why it behaves like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `nc` version you are using uses IPv6 by default. When you have `nc` listening on port 2000 the client connects to that bypassing your IPv4-only DNAT rule.

When nothing is listening on port 2000 it still tries to connect to that using IPv6 but fails, and then falls back to IPv4 where the DNAT rule will send it to the instance listening on port 4000.

The best solution I can think of at the moment is to simply create equivalent rules for both IPv4 and IPv6:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2000 -d 127.0.0.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:4000
ip6tables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2000 -d ::1 -j DNAT --to-destination '[::1]:4000'
```